# 2 Questions on Northwind SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, categories, northwind

I have 2 questions about the `Northwind` SQL Server sample database that I don't know how to solve

1. Show `CustomerID` for all customers who have at least three different products, but never use both products in the same category.

   Code I tried for this question:

   ```
   SELECT 
       CustomerID, p.ProductID,ProductName, CategoryID
   FROM 
       (Orders o 
   JOIN 
       [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID)
   JOIN
       Products p ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
   ```
2. Show `CustomerID` for customers who have orders from all categories.

I've been stuck on these queries for hours, please help guys!

This is link for `Northwind` sample database: https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far!

Comment: for 1)

SELECT CustomerID,p.ProductID,ProductName,CategoryID
FROM (Orders o join [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID)
join Products p ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID

only the join.. i didnt understand how to make the checks

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: ty for help , i am new here :)

Comment: Not clear on #1 - you say *have at least 3 different product* - in a **single** order? Also: *never use both* - you're talking about **3** products - what do you mean by *both* (that's referring to **2** of something.....)

Comment: not on single order.. customer ids that order on all their orders at least 3 products , but not from the same category , example: if 'AAA' order 20 products on 5 orders but there was 2 products on same category , they not count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT
    c.CustomerID, COUNT(DISTINCT p.CategoryID)
FROM 
    dbo.Customers c
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Orders o ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.[Order Details] od ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Products p ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
GROUP BY
    c.CustomerID
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.CategoryID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Categories)
```

Comment: and if i want to do it without knowing that there is 8 categories?

Comment: @EladJarby: then just use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Categories` instead

Answer (score -2):

This works for question #1:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, 
    od.productid, 
    p.ProductName, 
    COUNT(od.productid), 
    ct.Category
FROM [Order Details] od

INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] p on od.ProductID    = p.ProductID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Categories] ct on p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Orders] o on od.OrderID        = o.OrderID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customers] c on o.CustomerID   = c.CustomerID

GROUP BY od.productid,
         ct.CategoryID,
         p.ProductName,
         c.CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(od.productid) > 3
ORDER BY COUNT(od.productid) desc
;
```

Comment: Define "correct". Why is it correct? Also: Please try to avoid caps in the future. Also, [please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi Nestam, and welcome to Stack Overflow. you can see that Seth's edit to your answer is getting it into a more useful style, appropriate to this site - but it needs some more input from you too. Can you edit the answer to explain why this code is correct, and what about it solves the questioner's problem?